# Haskell simulate [1 .. n] with "until" function

Tags: haskell

I want to simulate the `[1 .. n]` functionality in Haskell but using the `until` function. I want to do something like this:

```
seq :: Int -> [Int]
seq a = until (\list -> if (length list) > a then True else False) (\x ->  x ++ ((tail x) + 1) ) [1]
```

And by calling `seq 5` it should return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. I HAVE to use the `until` function. It is a constraint if you may.

Comment: Your first lambda is egregiously over-complicated. It can be be written simply as `(\list -> (length list) > a)`, or eliminated entirely using `((> a) . length)`, although many may find the latter difficult to read.

Comment: `seq` is a highly inappropriate and confusing name for a user-defined function: it also exists as a primitive function/operator to force the evaluation of otherwise lazy thunks. also, don't use `sequence` because sequencing has a specific but widespread meaning, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a nice solution for this one is to not try to recover "how many steps we still need to do" from the list getting constructed, but instead, to use `until` on a pair of the list and the number of remaining elements to be added:

```
                      (5, []) -> 
(4, 5:[])           = (4, [5]) ->
(3, 4:[5])          = (3, [4, 5]) -> 
(2, 3:[4, 5])       = (2, [3, 4, 5]) -> 
(1, 2:[3, 4, 5])    = (1, [2, 3, 4, 5]) -> 
(0, 1:[2, 3, 4, 5]) = (0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Note that when the number of remaining elements is 0, that exactly means that the list we have constructed is the one we are after.

So we can implement this idea by making an `until` over a pair, and checking if the first element of the pair is equal to 0 to decide if we've finished:

```
seq0 :: Int -> (Int, [Int])
seq0 n = until (\(i, is) -> i == 0) (\(i, is) -> (i-1, i:is)) (n, [])
```

Of course, this will return the full pair `(0, [1..n])`, so we need to keep only the second element of the pair:

```
seq :: Int -> [Int]
seq n = snd (seq0 n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I found out another way of solving it:

```
seq :: Int -> [Int]    
seq a = until (\l -> (length l) >= a) (\x -> x ++ [((last x) + 1)]) [1]
```

Comment: Dr. "Cactus" Erdi's approach is both simpler and much more efficient. You should study it and think about why.